# Is there an alternative to Exposé for Windows 8 / 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, expose, task-switching

This question was asked some time ago (2009) here:
https://superuser.com/questions/30491/is-there-an-alternative-to-expose-for-windows

HOWEVER none of the answers cover projects updated since the release of Windows 8. They all seem mostly relevant to Windows Vista, few even referencing Windows 7.

Is there a way to get Exposé-like task switching in Windows 8 or 8.1?

Answer (score 3):

[Better Desktop Tool](http://www.betterdesktoptool.com/) is a fairly new one, it's the only new(ish) Expose clone that's gotten any coverage in the past year.
[Mission Control](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcsoft/) is newish, Open Source and has been updated fairly recently